# Best and easiest way to directly render CGPDFPage

Tags: ios, xcode, quartz-core, cgpdf

I am looking for an easy, direct and straightforward  way to render a `CGPDFPage` and view it on an iOS device.

The rendered  page should fill the view to which it is drawn and be crispy clear.

The less the code used in the method the better. However, if the amount of code required for the best result is too much, then it is preferred that the code be organised and well written.

Please do include a way to view in RGB color instead of CMYK.

I'd really appreciate it if you didn't suggest PDF readers/viewers or Github projects since I prefer not using them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a valid question. Anyways you should take a look to apple sample codes first. 
Here you go

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010281